# p5.js rotate unexpected results

Tags: javascript, rotation, p5.js

The `rotate()` function is not rotating to the correct number of degrees. The image shows the screen with no rotate. If I apply a rotate command by uncommenting line 14, the line is rotated to the 11 o'clock position, not to 9'oclock as I would have expected.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAuDl.png)

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  angleMode = DEGREES;
}

function draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(200, 102, 0);
  circle(100, 100, 180); //draw pivot
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(0, 0, 0);
  circle(100, 100, 15); //draw pivot point
  translate(100, 100); //move origin
  // rotate(180);
  //rotate(radians(180));
  line(0, 0, 90, 0);
}
```

However, if I use line 15 `(rotate(radians(180));` it works as expected. What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

[`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate) accepts radians as its parameter by default, not degrees. By converting degrees to radians, the argument makes sense. Without the conversion, it's some random number of turns, so you wind up at whatever arbitrary rotation 180 radians is.

Your attempt to set `angleMode`, `angleMode = DEGREES;` doesn't do what you expect. This overwrites the p5 function `window.angleMode`. p5 will warn you about the reassignment:

> You just changed the value of "angleMode", which was a p5 function. This could cause problems later if you're not careful.

```js
function setup() {
  angleMode = DEGREES;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Generally, setters in p5 aren't assignments. The correct usage is calling the function, [`angleMode(DEGREES)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/angleMode). This will allow `rotate()` to accept degrees by default so you don't need the `radians()` call.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(200, 102, 0);
  circle(100, 100, 180); // draw pivot
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(0, 0, 0);
  circle(100, 100, 15); // draw pivot point
  translate(100, 100); // move origin
  rotate(180);
  line(0, 0, 90, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

As an aside, canvas transformations like `translate()` and `rotate()` will stack, so `push()` and `pop()` and typically used to save and restore the context after these operations:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  push();
  noStroke();
  translate(100, 100);
  fill(200, 102, 0);
  circle(0, 0, 180);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(0, 0, 0);
  circle(0, 0, 15);
  rotate(180);
  line(0, 0, 90, 0);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Since you're already translating, you might as well do it first and use 0, 0 as the origin for your drawings.

But it turns out that `rotate()` isn't even necessary here: `line(0, 0, -90, 0);` will achieve the same result, which lets you avoid transformations entirely:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  const x = 100;
  const y = 100;
  noStroke();
  fill(200, 102, 0);
  circle(x, y, 180);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(0, 0, 0);
  circle(x, y, 15);
  line(x, y, x - 90, y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast and detailed response! I did see rotate with angle mode set to degrees on Youtube -The Coding Train "How to rotate shapes in p5.js"

Comment: The video uses `angleMode(DEGREES)` rather than `angleMode = degrees`. As discussed in my answer, the first is a setter function call, the second overwrites the p5 function with a number--almost definitely a mistake. (Reposted as my earlier comment had a typo)